# ¿Se pueden referenciar diferentes foreign keys para un mismo campo atributo?

Tags: sql, oracle-11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

Estoy trabajando en un código **Oracle SQL Express 11g**. Hasta el momento cuento con estas dos tablas:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTOS (
  OID_Proj INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  ubicacion VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS (
  OID_Proj INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  ubicacion VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Como se puede observar, la clave primaria de ambas tablas toma el mismo nombre `OID_Proj`, ya que la intención es que ambas tablas compartan una misma secuencia como primary key.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE SEC_Proj INCREMENT BY 1 START WITH 1;
```

Bien, el problema surge en la siguiente tabla (la cual pretende referenciar ambas claves primarias para un único campo atributo):

```
CREATE TABLE ENCARGADOS (
  OID_RP INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  OID_Proj INTEGER NOT NULL,
  OID_Coord INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_progdep FOREIGN KEY (OID_Proj) REFERENCES PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS(OID_Proj) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_eventos FOREIGN KEY (OID_Proj) REFERENCES EVENTOS(OID_Proj) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY (OID_Coord) REFERENCES COORDINADORES
);
```

**¿Es esto correcto? ¿Se puede hacer referencia a dos foreign keys para un mismo campo atributo?** No estoy del todo seguro de estar haciéndolo de manera correcta. ¿Existe una alternativa para, del mismo modo, no tener que depender de dos campos diferentes (uno para cada una de las referencias)?

Al intentar insertar en la tabla `ENCARGADOS`, Oracle SQL Developer lanza este error:

```
Informe de error -
  ORA-02291: integrity constraint (MRUANO.FK_PROGDEP) violated - parent key not found
  ORA-06512: at "MRUANO.REGISTRAR_EVENTO", line 8
  ORA-06512: at line 1
  02291. 00000 - "integrity constraint (%s.%s) violated - parent key not found"
  *Cause:    A foreign key value has no matching primary key value.
  *Action:   Delete the foreign key or add a matching primary key.
```

Espero que alguien pueda echarme una mano.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Si puedes referenciar dos `foreign keys` para un mismo campo.

Ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE EVENTOS (
  OID_Proj INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  ubicacion VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS (
  OID_Proj INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  nombre VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL,
  ubicacion VARCHAR2(50) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE ENCARGADOS (
  OID_RP INTEGER PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  OID_Proj INTEGER NOT NULL,
  OID_Coord INTEGER NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT FK_progdep FOREIGN KEY (OID_Proj) REFERENCES PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS(OID_Proj) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT FK_eventos FOREIGN KEY (OID_Proj) REFERENCES EVENTOS(OID_Proj) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

INSERT INTO EVENTOS VALUES (1,'Evento1','Ubicación1');
INSERT INTO EVENTOS VALUES (2,'Evento2','Ubicación2');

INSERT INTO PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS VALUES (1,'Programa1','Ubicación1');
INSERT INTO PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS VALUES (2,'Programa2','Ubicación2');
```

Si ahora inserto valores en la tabla encargados con `foregin keys` que ya existen como `primary key` en las tablas de referencia no hay problema.

```
INSERT INTO ENCARGADOS VALUES (1,1,1);
INSERT INTO ENCARGADOS VALUES (2,2,1);
```

Pero si intento incluir un registro que tiene un `OID_Proj` que no existe como `primary key` en las tablas de referencia

```
INSERT INTO ENCARGADOS VALUES (3,3,1);
```

> ORA-02291: integrity constraint (USER_4_A2827.FK_EVENTOS) violated -
>   parent key not found

El error que obtienes en tu caso te indica que `FK_progdep` no existe como `primary key` en la tabla `PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS` en el insert que intentas realizar.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta! Pero según veo en tu código no estarías teniendo en cuenta que tanto EVENTOS como PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS deben compartir la secuencia OID_Proj. Es decir, has usado las claves primarias '1' y '2' en ambas tablas. Mi intención es que sea una secuencia disjunta, es decir, compartida. Por ejemplo, eventos 1 y 2, y el primer programa deportivo insertado pues tendría el OID_Proj 3. No sé si ahora se ve un poco más clara mi intención.

Comment: @MarioRuano Tal como lo planteas no le encuentro el sentido, es posible que porque desconozca la lógica, pero si te estoy entendiendo no sería más sencillo tener una única tabla para eventos y programasdeportivos, la cual tendría la clave oid_proj, nombre, ubicación y un cuarto campo tipo que indique si es evento o programa deportivo? De ese modo evitas claves primarias no secuenciales y reduces a una única clave foránea en la tabla encargados. Así evitas el error de que la clave foránea no exista como primaria en una de las tablas y tienes un diseño más efectivo.

Comment: Muchas gracias @Carmen. Así lo he resulto finalmente, tal como indicas. Pero quisiera hacerte una pregunta. ¿De qué tipo sería la columna para indicar si es un evento o un programadeportivo, un enum?

Comment: Yo le asignaría un número a cada uno, 1 y 2 por ejemplo, y usaría un tinyint. Si sólo vas a tener esos dos tipos es sencillo saber cuál es cada uno, si puede haber más tipos ahora o en un futuro puedes hacer otra tabla que relacione el número con un varchar que lo describa.

Comment: Perfecto, así lo he resuelto. Gracias por los comentarios.

Answer (score 0):

Si he entendido bien, y los eventos y los programas deportivos son conjuntos disjuntos (lo que hay en uno no lo hay en otro y viceversa), este diseño fallaría siempre, porque al intentar insertar cualquier registro en la tabla de detalle le faltaría la referencia en, al menos, una de las dos tablas maestras, por definición. Vuelve a tu modelo ER y piensa de nuevo si los eventos y los programas deportivos no son la misma entidad, y por lo tanto no deberian ser la misma tabla (que los campos sean los mismos te da una pista en esa direccion)

Comment: Gracias por comentar y por tu sugerencia @GuillermoGarcía

Answer (score 0):

Como te indican "Carmen" hacerse se puede hacer, pero es un error de diseño, que ya indica Guillermo García, que va a provocar errores.

Respondiendo a tu pregunta ¿Es esto correcto? ¿Se puede hacer referencia a dos foreign keys para un mismo campo atributo?  la cuestión no es si puedes, sino la complicación que provocas. Te propongo mantener la relación entre Las tablas  PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS y EVENTOS, se debería tener una clave propia primaría y diferente en cada una de estas dos tablas, y la clave es una tercera tabla por ejemplo INDICE, que contiene como clave foránea las referencias cada una de las tablas, y su propio id, de manera que cuando quieras recuperar la información de PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS  y EVENTOS, desde ENCARGADOS, referencias el identificador de la tabla de INDICE.

A nivel de diseño puedes verlo en esta imagen
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por otra parte, entiendo que quieres insertar en ENCARGADOS sin que exista en PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS y EVENTOS, esto lo puedes conseguir con una inserción en cascada, en Oracle mecdiante un triger donde si id_eventos null y id_programs... null generara los insert para cada una de las tablas. O si usas la propuesta de INDICE, si no existe, crear los insert.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE EDITIONABLE TRIGGER TR_ENCARGADOS
BEFORE INSERT ON ENCARGOS
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW FOR EACH ROW
DECLARE valorSecuencia NUMBER := 0;
valorSecuencia_P NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
eventos_seq.NEXTVAL INTO valorSecuencia FROM DUAL;
INSERT INTO eventos (id_eventos, etc.... ) values (valorsecuencia, etc...)
PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS_SEQ INTO valorSecuencia_P from dual;
INSERT INTO PROGRAMASDEPORTIVOS(id_programas, etc.... ) values (valorsecuencia_P, etc...)
--con los valores de valorsecuencia y valorsecuencia_P ya se puede insertar encargos
 INSERT INTO encargos .......
END;
```